# Android add landscape orientation Button in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-button

I am a beginner in android, and i am trying to add a set of buttons in navigation drawer as shown in figure 2. i was create a TabLable in navigation drawer as figure 1. Now i want add button to the tablable.

[image: figure 1]

[image: figure 2]

my code look like this:

The first activity NavigationActivity.java

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

NavigationView navigationView = null;
Toolbar toolbar = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //Set the fragment initially
    PersonalFragment fragment = new PersonalFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    //How to change elements in the header programmatically
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView ProfileText = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.email);
    ProfileText.setText("马来西亚第一");
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.tools_bar, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if(id == R.id.action_search){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        PersonalFragment fragment = new PersonalFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        setTitle(R.string.title_home);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_award) {
        AwardFragment fragment = new AwardFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        setTitle(R.string.title_award);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_others) {
        OthersFragment fragment = new OthersFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        setTitle(R.string.title_others);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {
        setTitle(R.string.title_tools);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_setting) {
        setTitle(R.string.title_setting);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
        setTitle(R.string.title_about);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

And my XML file look like this:
**activity_main.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**nav_header_main.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_material_red"
    android:id="@+id/header_bgdimage"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_profile"
        app:border_color="#FF000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />


    <!--set default name-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wang Jian"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_above="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/profile_image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="user@host.com"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username" />



</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_tabs"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_bgdimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:background="#0F1E2D"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fillViewport="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**nav_custom_tab.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="190dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background_material_red"
    android:id="@+id/header_bgdimage"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_profile"
        app:border_color="#FF000000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />


    <!--set default name-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wang Jian"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_above="@+id/email"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/profile_image" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="user@host.com"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username" />



</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/nav_tabs"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_bgdimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:tabTextColor="#d3d3d3"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:background="#0F1E2D"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fillViewport="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**I'm a newbie at this stuff so any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.!**